# Converting Relay Node ID to Rails ID when updating related records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, relay

**Background:**

I have a `Location` model that `has_one` `Address` and `has_many` `Rooms`. When I want to update a location, either by updating its `name`, its `address` or its `rooms`, I'm using the following `InputObjects` to do this:

```rb
module Types
  # Input interface for creating locations
  class LocationUpdateType < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :id, ID, required: false
    argument :name, String, required: true
    argument :address, AddressUpdateType, required: true, as: :address_attributes
    argument :rooms, [RoomUpdateType], required: true, as: :rooms_attributes
  end

  class AddressUpdateType < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :id, ID, required: true
    # not sure if I need this or not but it's commented out for now
    # argument :location_id, ID, required: true
    argument :street, String, required: true
    argument :city, String, required: true
    argument :state, String, required: true
    argument :zip_code, String, required: true

    # I'm not using this yet but I'm anticipating it because
    # accepts_nested_attributes can use it as an indicator to destroy this address
    argument :_destroy, Boolean, required: false
  end

  class RoomUpdateType < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :id, ID, required: false
    # same thing with this ID.
    # argument :location_id, ID, required: true
    argument :name, String, required: true

    # accepts_nested_attributes flag for destroying related room records.
    # like above, I'm not using it yet but I plan to.
    argument :_destroy, Boolean, required: false
  end
end
```

When I make a GraphQL request, I'm getting the following in my logs:

```
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as JSON
  Variables: {"input"=>
  {"id"=>"TG9jYXRpb24tMzM=",
   "location"=>
    {"name"=>"A New Building",
     "address"=>
      {"city"=>"Anytown",
       "id"=>"QWRkcmVzcy0zMw==",
       "state"=>"CA",
       "street"=>"444 New Rd Suite 4",
       "zipCode"=>"93400"},
     "rooms"=>[{"id"=>"Um9vbS00Mw==", "name"=>"New Room"}]}}}

  mutation locationUpdate($input:LocationUpdateInput!) {
    locationUpdate(input: $input) {
      errors
      location {
        id
        name
        address {
          city
          id
          state
          street
          zipCode
        }
        rooms {
          id
          name
        }
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Which makes sense, I don't want to use real `ID`s on the client but the obfuscated Relay Node IDs.

**Problem:**

When my request goes to be resolved I'm using this Mutation:

```rb
module Mutations
  # Update a Location, its address and rooms.
  class LocationUpdate < AdminMutation
    null true
    description 'Updates a locations for an account'
    field :location, Types::LocationType, null: true
    field :errors, [String], null: true
    argument :id, ID, required: true
    argument :location, Types::LocationUpdateType, required: true

    def resolve(id:, location:)
      begin
        l = ApptSchema.object_from_id(id)
      rescue StandardError
        l = nil
      end

      return { location: nil, errors: ['Location not found'] } if l.blank?

      print location.to_h
      # return { location: nil }

      # This is throwing an error because it doesn't like the Relay Node IDs.
      l.update(location.to_h)

      return { location: nil, errors: l.errors.full_messages } unless l.valid?

      { location: l }
    end
  end
end
```

When I print the hash that gets passed into this resolver I get the following:

```rb
{
  :name=>"A New Building",
  :address_attributes=>{
    :id=>"QWRkcmVzcy0zMw==",
    :street=>"444 New Rd Suite 4",
    :city=>"Anytown",
    :state=>"CA",
    :zip_code=>"93400"
  },
  :rooms_attributes=>[{:id=>"Um9vbS00Mw==", :name=>"New Room"}]
}
```

When `l.update` runs, I get the following error:

`Couldn't find Room with ID=Um9vbS00Mw== for Location with ID=33`

This makes perfect sense to me because the Relay Node IDs aren't stored in the database so I guess I'm trying to figure out how to convert the `room.id` from a Relay Node ID, to the ID in the database.

Now, I could dig through the hash and use the `ApptSchema.object_from_id` and convert all the Relay Node IDs to Rails IDs but that requires a database hit for each one. I see the documentation for `Connections` listed [here](https://graphql-ruby.org/relay/connections.html) but this looks more like how to deal with queries and pagination.

Do I need to send the database IDs to the client if I plan on updating records with related records? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of Relay Node IDs? Is there a way to configure my Input object types to convert the Relay Node IDs to Rails IDs so I get the proper IDs in the hash sent to my resolver?

Comment: Not super familiar with relay, but sounds like you need to cache the relay node ids? Either by providing a lookup for them (redis?) or store the relay node id within the rails model? Basically spend a high upfront cost to do the conversion so you don't need to do it later. If not, why this isn't possible may provide some insight into other solutions.

Comment: If you're not familiar with Relay, my guess is you're probably not familiar with GraphQL either? If you are, then I can tell you this: I could just pass the DB id with the Model Type as a JSON response and then send it back when I do the GQL request. I just think that defeats the purpose of using Relay because someone could get access to that DB ID using a debugger and that would give them insight into other data in the database. I don't think storing the Relay IDs in the database is the proper solution to this, but I could be using GraphQL incorrectly here.

Comment: Actually somewhat familiar with GraphQL which is why I didn't mention it, just didn't use Relay with it. A quick check again shows Relay is for React. In which case, my suggestion is simplier. Never pass actual IDs to the client. Take a look at the `friendly_id` gem. Though that may be solving a different problem. Unclear exactly what insight you are trying to prevent leaking, if it's sequential ordering (IE: given an ID of 5000, an ID of 1-4999 is probably valid) then using friendly id and `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(24)` to create slugs is a fairly standard solution to prevent that.

Comment: Note the randomness of `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(24)` is approximately equal to that of a UUID (and cleaner), which is why I mention it.

Comment: Relay and the GQL standard were created by Facebook (I believe) so you CAN you use it with a React.js+Relay client solution but Relay is a standard just like GQL is. You can follow it or not, its up to you. Relay supports a `clientMutationId` that can get passed with requests and is to be returned with the response. I don't support that in my project but it IS a Relay stand so my guess is that you can support Relay on Node.js on the backend or with say Angular on the front end. However, I'll consider looking into both of those solutions, thank you.

Comment: And regarding 'insight' what I mean is not having urls like `/posts/1` but instead something like `/posts/AsdOowhc==` which obfuscates the `id` so that someone malicious isn't trying to access `/posts/2` for example if they're not authorized to access that resource. Of course, it's up to me to prevent this from happening but essentially, you're giving someone 'insight' into what your data looks like.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what the friendly ID gem is intended for. Technically, it's used for making slugs like `/posts/did-you-get-that-thing-i-sent-you` (the `did-you-get-that-thing-i-sent-you` part is the slug), but you can also use it generate things like `/posts/8o3qnyrvlowa`, as well as automatically update the slug if you change the post title. highly recommend you look into it, it may completely sidestep the issue you are having. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Really you shouldn't be trying to avoid going to `posts/1` within anything on the browser side. If it's hit the browser it should be assumed the user can find out about it, one way or another. Only way to ensure security is to avoid the need for the ID to be referenced client side. Though security is only one of several reasons you might not want to use routes in the form `/posts/1`. Another is that you look "small" if  a user can tell you probably only have a few 100 or a few 1000 records. Yet another is the link is more interesting if you have something like `posts/super-cool-post` instead.

Comment: I'm confused about the first sentence in your last comment because of a double negative. Are you saying I SHOULD avoid urls like `posts/1`? If so, I think we're on the same page. I'll definitely look into the `friendly_id` gem and if it does solve my problem, I'll reply here and have you create an answer post so I can give you the rep points you deserve. Thank you for spending the time in the comment section here either way.

Comment: Sorry about that, but you are right. Often one wishes to avoid `posts/1` and using `friendly_id` is a solid way to go about it.

Comment: @Nuclearman if you'd like credit for helping me solve this issue, post a summary of what you explained here and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research, it seems that Relay UUIDs aren't really feasible when trying to update records through relationships. I think Relay assumes that you're using something like MongoDB which does this with their record's primary keys by default.

Using `friendly_id` as @Nuclearman has suggested seems to be the best way to obfuscate urls. What I've decided to do is to add `friendly_id` to records that I want to view in a "detail mode" like `/posts/3aacmw9mudnoitrswkh9vdrt` by creating a concern like this:

```rb
module Sluggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :slug, presence: true

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :create_slug_id, use: :slugged

    private def create_slug_id
      # Try to see if the slug has already been created before generating a new one.
      @create_slug_id ||= self.slug
      @create_slug_id ||= SecureRandom.alphanumeric(24)
    end
  end
end
```

And then including the concern in any model you want to have `friendly_ids` in like so:

```rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  include Sluggable
end
```

Then in your GraphQL type do something like this:

```rb
module Types
  class LocationType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false

    # Only include this for model types that have friendly_id
    field :friendly_id String, null: false

    field :name, String, null: false

    # AddressType and RoomType classes won't have friendly_id because
    # I'm not going to have a url like /location/3aacmw9mudn/address/oitrswkh9vdrt
    # or /location/3aacmw9mudn/rooms/oitrswkh9vdrt
    field :address, AddressType, null: false
    field :rooms, [RoomType], null: false
  end
end

module Types
  class LocationUpdateType < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :name, String, required: true
    argument :address, AddressUpdateType, required: true, as: :address_attributes
    argument :rooms, [RoomUpdateType], required: true, as: :rooms_attributes
  end
end
```

You might want to add `friendly_id` to all your models but my guess is you may only want it for "important" ones. Variables passed to the query no longer use UUIDs for dependent relationships but only for objects you're updating when finding them by ID like so:

```
{"input"=>
  {"id"=>"3aacmw9mudn",
   "location"=>
    {"name"=>"A New Building",
     "address"=>
      {"city"=>"Anytown",
       "id"=>"4",
       "state"=>"CA",
       "street"=>"444 New Rd Suite 4",
       "zipCode"=>"93400"},
     "rooms"=>[{"id"=>"13", "name"=>"New Room"}]}}}
```

And now your resolver might look something like:

```rb
module Mutations
  # Update a Location, its address and rooms.
  class LocationUpdate < AdminMutation
    null true
    description 'Updates a locations for an account'
    field :location, Types::LocationType, null: true
    field :errors, [String], null: true
    argument :id, ID, required: true
    argument :location, Types::LocationUpdateType, required: true

    def resolve(id:, location:)
      # Here, we're passing the friendly_id to this resolver (see above)
      # not that actual ID of the record.
      l = Location.friendly.find(id)

      return { l: nil, errors: ['Location not found'] } if l.blank?

      l.update(location.to_h)

      return { location: nil, errors: l.errors.full_messages } unless l.valid?

      { location: l }
    end
  end
end
```